# Standalone Script for Custom Functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am developing an add-on with custom functions.  This also includes a sidebar.

When I test the addon, I do the authorizations and the sidebar functions as it should.

I am unable, however, to use the custom functions - they just don't appear when I start typing.  I know they should work ok, since I prepared them in a bounded script originally and they were fine there.  Then copy & paste to the standalone script, but no joy.

There are 3 OAuth scopes required by the script:

https://mail.google.com/

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

I then updated the appsscript.json file to include the scopes above, as suggested here:
[Google Setting Scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes)

I'm assuming this has something to do with authorizations.  What should I be looking for?  Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are experiencing the following issue, reported in Issue Tracker some time ago:

- [Issue #36763437. "Test as add-on" from standalone project to Google Sheets doesn't link custom functions](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763437)

Custom functions don't seem to work when the add-on is being tested with `Test as add-on`. Crucially, this problem only seems to show up while in test mode: when the add-on is published, custom functions do show up.

Anyone you wants to keep track of this can click the star on the top left in the referenced page.

In any case, since the rest of the add-on actions seem to be working correctly, most probably the custom functions will work after the add-on is published. I understand, though, that not being able to test the add-on before publishing can be frustrating.